# Cutting a string when it hits a dot

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a variable called image_name. example below

```
$image_name = "hello.png";
```

I want to cut the string when it see's the dot. Because I want to add a randomised int so the name cant be duplicated. For example at the moment in my code I have

```
$image_name = substr($image_name, 0, 10) . time() . rand(0, 9999);
```

and with the test string above it would return something like

```
hello.png13953322416647
```

My aim is have the string name equal to hello13953322416647.png - showing the .png after all timestamp and random number

So does anyone know how cut the string when it hits a dot in a string and then add it at the end..?

Thanks guys

Comment: Have you tried using `substr($image_name, 0, strrpos($image_name, '.')). time().rand(0, 9999).substr($image_name, strrpos($image_name, '.'))` ?

Answer (score 4):

I would use the pathinfo function. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$path_detail = pathinfo( $image_name );
$new_image_path = sprintf( "%s%s%s%s", $path_detail['filename'], time(), rand( 0,9999), $path_detail['extension']);
```

Comment: +1: This is the correct way to do it.